# c# how i can reset Process Bar and start it again

Tags: c#, progress-bar

In WFA (c#) i have Process Bar. I have 2 Process and want to show process bar each time when process is start. But it doesn't work!:

```
    public void ProcessStart(int ProcessMaximumValue)
    {
        progressBar.Maximum = ProcessMaximumValue;
    }

    public void ProcessEnd()
    {
        progressBar.Value = 0;
    }

        ProcessStart(4);
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            progressBar.PerformStep();
        }
        ProcessEnd();


        ProcessStart(3);
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        {
            progressBar.PerformStep();
        }
        ProcessEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the to 1 if your step is 1, like : progressBar.Step = 1;
PerformStep() adds onto progress.value the Step value.